# JSON array not working for $http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am new to angular and trying to develop an application having nested 
   `ng-repeat` and after submitting the `form` it should hit the `rest api`.
    I have been using `$http` to make `rest api` calls. The code gets submitted
    with normal data but does not get submitted with nested `ng-repeat` when i 
    click the `save` button. Below I have provided the code with details.
    The whole data should be shown in the `console`. I might have made some 
    mistake somewhere.Thanks in advance.

JS

```
 $scope.saveVenFormData = function(vendet){
     console.log($scope.vendet);
     $scope.venFullAddress.push({
        'vendorName': $scope.name,
        'panNum': $scope.panNum,
        'personName': $scope.venBusDetails.personName,
        'mobileNum': $scope.venBusDetails.mobileNum,
        'workNum': $scope.workNum,
        'emailid': $scope.emailid,
        'addressLine1': $scope.addressLine1,
        'addressLine2': $scope.addressLine2,
        'city': $scope.city,
        'state': $scope.state
        });
     var dataObj = $scope.venFullAddress;
    // console.log($scope.dataObj);

     $http.get('/showVendors').success(function(data){
        console.log(angular.toJson(data));
    });
    var res = $http.post('http://localhost:8080/dman/mm', dataObj);
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = data;
    });
    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    }); 
 };
```

JSON structure:

```
{
 "vendor": {
    "vendorName": "",
    "panNum": "",
    "venBusDetails": [{
            "personName": "",
            "mobileNum": "",
            "workNum": "",
            "emailid": "",
            "venContDetails": [{
                    "addressLine1": "",
                    "addressLine2": "",
                    "city": "",
                    "state": ""
                }]
        }]
   }
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/nP8R92KNkz8JEHpvH56S?p=catalogue
    For convenience I have added a json structure. I need to access all the 
    data from the form and hit the rest api.
    The above is the link to the plunker. Thank you.

Comment: [JSPretty.com](http://jspretty.com). Use it. Please.

Comment: You need to also show the form - that's where your ng-repeat is.

Comment: While you a waiting for an answer to this question, try writing a small test case with only one form element and one nested `ng-repeat`. For more information, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dev8080 The Plunker demo is right there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$scope.dataObjToPost = {
  "vendor": {
    "vendorName": $scope.vendet.vendorName,
    "panNum": $scope.vendet.panNum,
    "venBusDetails": [{
      "personName": $scope.venBusDetails[0].personName,
      "mobileNum": $scope.venBusDetails[0].mobileNum,
      "workNum": $scope.venBusDetails[0].workNum,
      "emailid": $scope.venBusDetails[0].emailid,
      "venContDetails": [{
        "addressLine1": $scope.venContDetails[0].addressLine1,
        "addressLine2": $scope.venContDetails[0].addressLine2,
        "city": $scope.venContDetails[0].city,
        "state": $scope.venContDetails[0].state
      }]
    }]
  }
} //And send this data to POST method
```

You used `$scope.name` in JS file but in HTML view you used `ng-model="vendet.vendorName"`. Thats why it is always `undefined`.

[UPDATED ANSWER Plunk LINK IS HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/i4VvU03BWEpKw6uOBUpf)

Comment: thanks for the answer. If venBusDetails is increased then we will increment it by $index, so will it be venBusDetails[index] or id bcoz ngRepeat checks for duplicates.

Comment: Yes it will be as per length of array. And you can prepare this data in loop which will be length of array i.e length of `venBusDetails`

Comment: I hope this help you